# How can I invoke a script at server side using the GUI of the already available open source server monitoring tools like Nagios, Cacti e.t.c.?

Tags: server-monitoring

I want to invoke a script at server side using the GUI of the already available open source server monitoring tools like Nagios, Cacti e.t.c. But the call for the script must be without using any agent/deamon and then 
the data which script will return is directed to the GUI. So please suggest me the available open source tool whose GUI provide API to develop the plugin which can call the script without using any agent/deamon.

Answer (score 0):

Normally for cacti you will find that there are 'plugins' eg. weathermap, notification, threshold.... that provide this GUI. For nagios I am not to sure, but for ICINGA 2 you have the plugin called nagvis, you also call information via scripts.